# USB Keyboard Protocol

Tags: keyboard, usb, hid

I am trying to build an HID keyboard. I got my STM32 MCU to recognize as a keyboard, but for some reason when I try to send the HID report (8 bytes) using Endpoint 1 in Interrupt mode. The host side doesn't get the data(key pressed) . Do I need to use the standard method Get_Report ?

I have also tried another implementation on a AT90USB1287. It works well but for some odd reason I must set the endpoint to 3 in order to get it working.

i am wondering if the USB HID keyboard protocol only looks at end point 3 when getting data?

Answer (score 2):

The USB HID (keyboard) protocol uses the endpoint you specify in your USB descriptor. Look at the Endpoint address in the Endpoint descriptor.